# How to use k channels in CNN for k FC Layers

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have an encoder, which outputs a tensor with shape `(bn, c * k, 32, 32)`. I now want produce k means with shape `(bn, k, 1, 2)`. So the means are 2-dim coordinates. To do so, I want to use k FC Layers, while for each mean k_i I only want to use c channels.

So my idea is, that I reshape the encoder output `out` to a 5d tensor with shape `(bn, k, c, 32, 32)`. Then I can use the flattened `out[:, 0]` ... `out[:, k]` as input for the k linear layers.

The trivial solution would be to define the linear layers manually:

```
self.fc0 = nn.Linear(c * 32 * 32, 2)
...
self.fck = nn.Linear(c * 32 * 32, 2)
```

Then I could define the forward pass for each mean as follows:

```
mean_0 = self.fc0(out[:, 0].reshape(bn, -1))
...
mean_k = self.fck(out[:, k].reshape(bn, -1))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Not entirely sure about it, but couldn't you use strided convolution to do that?

Comment: I don't think that's what I want. To give a little more information about the background: I want to find the keypoints/landmarks of the input image. The idea is, that I assign each keypoint k a number of feature maps c. That's, why the output of the encoder has the shape `(bn, k, c, 32, 32)`. Now I want those c feature maps to predict its keypoint, which is a 2-dim coordinate. Essentially, I want a separate fc layer for each keypoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a grouped convolution. You can let `axis=1` have `k*c` tensors, so the input shape is `(bn, k*c, 32, 32)`. Then use a [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) convolution layer with `2*k` filters and set to receive `k` groups so it's not a fully connected *channel-wise* (only `k` groups of `c` maps: convolves `c` at a time.

```
>>> bn = 1; k = 5; c = 3
>>> x = torch.rand(bn, k*c, 32, 32)
>>> m = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=c*k, out_channels=2*k, kernel_size=32, groups=k)

>>> m(x).shape
torch.Size([4, 10, 1, 1])
```

Which you can then reshape to your liking.

---

In terms of number of parameters. A typical `nn.Conv2d` usage would be:

```
>>> m = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=c*k, out_channels=2*k, kernel_size=32)
>>> sum(layer.numel() for layer in m.parameters())
153610
```

Which is exactly `c*k*2*k*32*32` weights, plus `2*k` biases.

In your case, you would have

```
>>> m = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=c*k, out_channels=2*k, kernel_size=32, groups=k)
>>> sum(layer.numel() for layer in m.parameters())
30730
```

Which is exactly `c*2*k*32*32` weights, plus `2*k` biases. *i.e.* `k` times less than the previous layer. A given filter's has only `c` layers (not `k*c`) which means it will have an input with `c` channels (*i.e.* one of the `k` groups containing `c` maps)

Comment: But doesn't this approach share the weights while calculating the means? I want, that the predictions of the mean k_0 are solely depended on the c feature maps assigned to that specific keypoint i.e. the channels x[:, 0]. I might misunderstand your concept though.

Comment: See my edit, I added some clarifications. Grouped convolutions will not be fully connected *channel wise*. The result of a given 2D output will only depend on `c` channels of the input tensor

Comment: Ahh very interesting! I was not aware of  the group parameter in `nn.Conv2d`. Yes that seems to work as well. I think both answers here achieve the goal I am aiming for. I am wondering, which approach is better suited! Do you have an idea here?

Comment: Can't beat a one-liner! Also I would assume it's more efficient to use a convolution since the whole operation will happen in one go, *versus* `k` separate `nn.Linear` calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great concept I have just learned :)

Comment: I have another question: how can I know, which channels correspond to which mean? In other words, if I reshape the input x to `(bn, k, c, 32, 32)`, is it correct that `m[:, 0]` belongs to `x[:, 0]`? Or should I rather reshape to `(bn, c, k, 32, 32)` and then `m[:, 0]` belongs to `x[:, :, 0]`?

Comment: You don't have to reshape, the input tensor must be `(bn, k*c, 32, 32)`

Comment: Yes that's true, but I want to apply some operations afterwards. To be precise, I want to produce a gaussian distribution around the means and thereby generate k heatmaps. The heatmaps have shape `(bn, k, 32, 32)`. Each heatmap therefore corresponds to c channels, and I want to do an element wise multiplication of the channels with their heatmap. That way, the feature maps are focused around the corresponding means. The way I could achieve that, is the following. by reshaping x into `(bn, k, c, 32, 32) and the heatmaps with `heatmaps.unsqueeze(2).repeat(1, 1, c, 1, 1) and multiply.

Comment: I would go with a reshape to `(bn, k, c, 32, 32)` (I see it as a batch of `k` `c`-channel `32x32` maps)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using **nn.ModuleList**:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class fclist(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, k):
        super().__init__()
        '''
        k: no. of clusters
        '''
        self.k = k
        '''
        .
        .
        .
        Other previous layers
        .
        .
        '''

        c = 1

        self.out_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(k):
            self.out_layers.append(nn.Linear(c*32*32, 2))

    def forward(self, x):
        '''
        .
        .
        .
        pass throgh previous layers
        .
        .
        '''
        x = [layer(x) for layer in self.out_layers]
        return x
```

Sample output:

```
>>> net =  fclist(k=3)
>>> inp = torch.randn(1, 1*32*32)
>>> net(inp)
[tensor([[-0.7319, -0.2686]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>), tensor([[-0.6248,  0.9180]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>), tensor([[0.2532, 0.1387]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)]
```

Comment: Not sure if that's what OP meant by *"more efficient way to do that?"*

Comment: Thanks, I think that is precisely what I was looking for! :)